# How the set RTC as wake up source and set a specific time on all the days using sys file system

Tags: linux, sys, wakeup, real-time-clock, sabre

I am using a imx6 SabreSD. I need to set the RTC as the wake up source, and I need to set a specific time on all the day,say 12 midnight(may not be in power down mode at that time)
I have a sample 
    echo +x > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm; RTC will wake up system after x seconds

using this i can wake up system after x seconds. But i need this as 00:00:01 as time

I go to suspend state by 
    echo standby > /sys/power/state

Is there any way. Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Wake up at midnight:

```
date +%s -d'day 0' >/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

Wake up at 00:00:01:

```
date +%s -d'day 00:00:01' >/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```